# Multiple infopath forms in one SP List

Tags: infopath

Is it possible to have multple infopath forms in one sharepoint site? I have read that is possible but the explanation is quite complicated.

My scenario:

1. I have an SP list
2. I have few infopath forms which needs to be connected (Vendor, Asset and Customer Forms)

Can i publish this 3 forms in one sharepoint list?

If yes, can you help me by explaining - am exploring the sharepoint functionality

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can't "publish multiple InfoPath forms to one list".

Meanwhile,

- you can use multiple views in InfoPath as mentioned at [How to Create Multiple Views in Infopath](http://blog.fpweb.net/how-to-create-multiple-views-in-infopath/#.WIcvJPl96Uk)
- Or you can replace the list with library and use multiple forms by

  - saving every form as a site content type,

[image]

- then allow content type in the advanced setting for your list setting.
- and in list setting > add a content type from existing content type below InfoPath form.

Comment: Hi M.Qassas! I appreciate your reply. So i need to publish it in Library and not list correct?

Comment: in form library , then use it as content type in your library